# Tag box on on question edit to small

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, meta

When I went to edit a question here on meta I saw that the box to add Tags was to small (or the tags are just to low), here are some screens from different browsers:

Google Chrome version:34.0.1847.116 m
Opera version:20.0.1387.91
[image]

FireFox version:28.0
[image]

Internet Explorer version:11.0.9600.16659
[image]

Not running any user scripts, only extensions are Adblock (2.6.29) and FireBug Lite (1.4.0.11967) but those don't seem to effect it when turned off.

Comment: No repro in Chrome. What version? Any browser extensions or userscripts that might cause this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Updated the question with browser versions and other info!

Comment: Oh, turns out my version is outdated. Now updating, let's see... yep that's a brand new bug happening only in the latest Chrome version.