# This (meta) question already has an answer here? Not really

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, meta, ios-app

Here in Meta Stack Exchange we can close a question as duplicate of a question without any answer whatsoever. I won't get into whether it's right or wrong, just stating this as a dry fact.

For example [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230698/tag-box-on-on-question-edit-to-small) is closed as dupe of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229833/tags-feeling-a-little-shy-again) which got no answers yet:

> [image]

The above is the banner as seen in the website itself, however when viewing the question in the app (iOS for me but most likely it's the same in android app) what I see is this:

> [image]

So the message is wrong and misleading, as the dupe got no answers. Can the message in app be consistent with the message in the site itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated the banner in beta version 0.1.72 to make it match the description above.

[image]

Comment: from dupe-closures I observe at meta, more accurate wording would likely be "a _possibly inexact_ duplicate" (not that I complain:)