# How about an option to choose that your question is a duplicate even if it doesn’t have an answer?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, information-display

A question closed as a duplicate normally displays a message stating that it already has an answer elsewhere. [Apparently, though, on Meta sites where questions can be closed even if the existing question does *not* have an answer, the message is modified to reflect that.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231154/this-meta-question-already-has-an-answer-here-not-really)

Despite this, the message presented to the poster when someone suggests a duplicate does not reflect the possibility that the question could be a duplicate even if the original has no answer. You are presented with two choices:

> That solved my problem!

Or:

> No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how.

[image: Screenshot showing choices]

In cases where the same question has been asked but has no answer, neither choice is accurate. The question is not different, but the problem has not been solved.

Can this message be modified to allow us a choice where it is a duplicate even though the problem has not been solved?

Comment: Better just change the button text to "Yes, I got the same issue" for example instead of adding a new one.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I’m fine with that.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog What am I supposed to do now? I can't click "that solved my problem" for your suggestion, because it didn't.

Comment: Ignore the words it uses and just think of it as an "insta-close" button.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog That is indeed the result, but it forces me to lie.

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe, since this one here is about cases where there are no answers at all. But won't use my hammer since it's still very related. /cc @Sonic

Comment: @ShadowWizard As is the other one. That one just generally says "unanswered", which refers to the general definition of the term as used in the tab with the same name.